# Asible Replace a string with regex that uses groups changing only one and preserving others

Tags: ansible

I have a XML File to configure certain process, the XML nodes have two patters:

```
<Node>  Content </Node>
<OtherNode property="value"> Content </OtherNode>
```

I need to replace **Content** by preserving the structure of the XML tag and only changing the specific Node, this imposes an important restriction since **Content** can be a value that is the same in other tags and those should not be changed for obvious reasons.

I have a Regex that allows to select only a specific node, based on the name of the node and without taking into account whether or not it has properties, said regex divides the tag into groups, five to be specific.

```
(<\s*OtherNode.*>)(\s*)(Content)(\s*)(<\/\s*OtherNode\s*>)
```

Of the five groups, I just need to replace the third and preseve the others. Is there any way to do this in ansible? I have this, but not works:

```
  - name: Replace configuration in xml 
    replace:
      path: /path/to/file/configuration.xml
      regexp: '(<\s*{{node}}.*>)(\s*)(currentvalue)(\s*)(<\/\s*{{node}}\s*>)'
      replace: '(<\s*{{node}}.*>)(\s*)(newvalue)(\s*)(<\/\s*{{node}}\s*>)'
```

It is necessary to do it with ansible because there are several nodes in the network that must be updated.

Thank you very much for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use backreferences inside `replace`:

```
replace: '\1\2newvalue\4\5'
```